# Forms authentication ASP.NET webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, forms-authentication

I have an ASP.NET webforms application that uses forms authentication. For the pages that don't need authentication I have those in a separate folder. All other pages are in the main folder and use authentication. This all works.

The application now needs to serve images. So, if I have a url like `https://mysite/{id}` I look up an image in the database for the specified `id` and serve the image. To serve the image, I have code in a `BeginRequest` method in the `global.asax`. I check to see if the url is of type `https://mysite/{id}` and serve the image by doing a `response.write` and write the bytes of the image.

When I do the `response.write` the forms authentication kicks in and sends me to a login page.

So, for a url of `https://mysite/{id}`, I don't want to do forms authentication, but I don't know how to turn authentication off for this type of url without turning off authentication for pages I do want authentication for.

Is there a way to not do forms authentication in the `BeginRequest` method? Is there a property or method I can call in the `BeginRequest` to turn forms authentication off?

Comment: Are you calling response.end too?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways :

1.(EASYONE)ACCORDING TO THIS [DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/aspnet/development/forms-based-authentication) use the forms authentication configuration in web.config to exclude URLs. You can add an  element with a path attribute for the URL pattern you want to exclude, and set enabled="false" on the  element:

```
<location path="images/">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

2.In your BeginRequest handler, check the requested URL and if it matches your excluded pattern, call HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(string.Empty), null); This will manually set an anonymous user principal before the forms auth module executes or u can Create a custom forms authentication module that overrides the default one, and in the OnAuthenticate method add logic to skip authentication based on the URL.